# WHERE NOT() in cypher neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having trouble with a simple cypher query.  The query is:

```
MATCH (u:user { google_id : 'example_user' })--(rm:room)--(a:area),
    (c:category { name : 'culture:Yoruba' })--(o:object) 
WHERE NOT (a-[:CONTAINS]->o) 
RETURN DISTINCT o.id
```

The "WHERE NOT.." is being ignored and I am getting back the nodes with incoming :CONTAINS relationships from the area nodes.  If I take out the "NOT" function, then I correctly only get back the nodes that have this a-->o relationship.

I think I have a weak understanding of NOT()

Comment: It seemed to work here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/4nukek Could you reproduce the problem there and share a new link?

Comment: Be careful also about a disconnected pattern like that, you will get the cross product of whatever is matched individually in the two pattern parts. On a small graph it may not matter, but on a larger graph it will be expensive. I may be better to break the query with `WITH a MATCH (c:category ...` than to filter the return to distinct values.

Comment: Look here for reproduced problem: [link](http://console.neo4j.org/r/nn691p)  The last query should not return object 3704.  I tried using the WITH A syntax. Thanks for that.

Comment: I started answering but Jim beat me to it and it's a good answer. Returning only distinct result sometimes hides unexpected effects from path combinations. Also, you may be better of declaring relationship type and direction in the pattern, and you could try using a longer pattern in the path predicate in the `WHERE` clause (use match to reach new results, use where to limit). You could experiment with something like this: http://console.neo4j.org/r/xlvmsy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trad,

The query is returning just what you asked it to. In your example at the link, there are three areas. None of the objects are contained by the first two areas, so all three nodes are returned. If you change the RETURN line to

```
RETURN a.area_number, o.id
```

you will see this.

I don't know about your larger problem context, but if you want to know about objects that aren't in **any** area, then the query

```
MATCH (o:object)
WHERE NOT (o)<-[:CONTAINS]-()
RETURN o.id
```

will accomplish the task.

Grace and peace,

Jim